# How to make dependant properties in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a need to create a LWC component for record page which will show related records filtering them by their record type. Due to requirements I can't use standart single related list and need a custom LWC.
In that LWC I need to have 2 properties

- Relation field - field which stores related objects (like
  Contracts__r)
- Record type - record type for that related object (like
  Customer)

I have build 2 apex classes extending VisualEditor.DynamicPickList for this, but how can I show record types based on the object selected in the first property?

```
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
    <property label="Related object" name="relationField" type="String" datasource="apex://RelatedFieldsPicklist"/>
    <property label="Record type" name="recordType" type="String" datasource="apex://RecordTypePicklist"/>
</targetConfig>
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Unfortunately this isn't possible at the moment as each property is independent.

Comment: As above, not yet possible with LWCs in Lightning Pages - it's a shame that Flow's [Custom Property Editor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_flow_custom_property_editor_lwc_example) isn't supported (yet?) in the Lightning App Builder.